# How to have a function finish a for loop before returning

Tags: javascript, axios

Below is the code I type to go through an array and stick the data needed into an output array, then ultimately return the output array:

```
var stocks = ['AAPL', 'BMY']

let getInfo = arr => {
    let output = []
    arr.forEach(i => {
    var root = 'https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/profile/' + i + '?apikey=myAPIKey'
        axios.get(root)
        .then((data) => {
            output.push(data.data)
            })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('error', e)
            })
  })
  console.log('output: ', output)
  return output
}

getInfo(stocks)
```

The console.log just logs an empty array, which makes me think it goes to the return statement before the for loop finishes executing. Does anybody know the best way to have the for loop finish first, and then finally return the output array?

Answer (score 1):

That's because axios is the asynchronous method and return statement should be returned before the `axios().then()`.

Use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and use `async/await`

```js
var stocks = ['AAPL', 'BMY']

let getInfo = async arr => {
  let output = []
  const promises = []
  arr.forEach(i => {
    var root = 'https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/profile/' + i + '?apikey=myAPIKey'
    promises.push(axios.get(root))
      .then((data) => {
        output.push(data.data)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log('error', e)
      })
  })
  const result = await Promise.all(promises)
  output = result.map(r => r.data)
  console.log('output: ', output)
  return output
}

getInfo(stocks)
```

Comment: Thanks! I got this as a result when I ran the code: [object Promise] { ... }

Comment: there was a typo, i just updated. try to check again

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await keywords to get the axios call to wait. Like:

```js
let getInfo = async arr => {
    let output = []
 
    try {
      for(var i in arr) {
        var root = 'https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/profile/' + arr[i] + '?apikey=myAPIKey'
        var data = await axios.get(root);
        output.push(data.data);
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
       // oops
       console.log('error', e);
       return null;
    }

    return output;

  }
```

Comment: Thanks! When I tried making the function as a closure with var answer = getInfo(array) and then console.log answer, it returns [object Promise] { ... }

Comment: Yes! getInfo returns a Promise since it is async. You can eitehr use it with await, like `answer = await getinfo(array)` or with then: `getInfo(array).then(output=>{ // do what you want  with output })` be carefult, using await is not allowed in the main body of your program, it should inside another async function ...

Answer (score 0):

`Axios.get` returns a promise, it is executed asynchronously while the rest of your lambda continues its execution.

Look into `Promise.all()` so that you can log output after all the promises have resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var stocks = ["AAPL", "BMY"];

let getInfo = async (arr) => {
  const output = await Promise.all(
    arr.map(
      (i) =>
        new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(
              `https://fmpcloud.io/api/v3/profile/${i}?apikey=myAPIKey`
            );
            resolve(data);
          } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
          }
        })
    )
  );

  console.log("output: ", output);
  return output;
};

getInfo(stocks);
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use forEach. Use a for/of loop.  Next,  use async/await to synchronize on the
axios calls. That should do it.